# angularjs element manipulation

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, angular-elements

I am confused about angularjs manipulation.

How come:

```
   angular.element("#elementID").is(':visible') ;   // works
   angular.element("#elementID").slideUp() ;   // works
   angular.element("#elementID").style.opacity = 1 ; // **doesn't work**

   angular.element("#elementID")[0].style.opacity = 1 ;   // works
   angular.element("#elementID").css('opacity' : 1) ;   // **doesn't work**
```

I have a Cordova/Ionic app, jquery is installed.  I feel the `.css(field : value)` should be working.

The various methods keep tripping me up.  Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Does `angular.element` return a `jQuery` object prototype, or is it an Angular-specific flavor? Nevermind, I answered my own question, [it does](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). Please make sure Angular can see jQuery, because _"jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery"_. This means that it is not a fully-featured replacement for jQuery. I suspect jQuery is not actually available to your Angular application.

Comment: Also, I believe the 3rd line should be: `angular.element("#elementID").get(0).style.opacity = 1` This is because jQuery does not have access to the `style` property of the raw element.

Comment: AFIK `get()` isn't a function of angluarJS.  According to the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element - `css()` should be working...but also `is`, `slideUp()' work but are not defined here either.  Makes me wonder if Ionic extended it.

Comment: `$.fn.get` is a function in `jQuery`. It unwraps the native `Element`. The actual DOM element has a `style` property, not the jQuery object.